# IDictionary.Item returns wrong type

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an issue with the IDictionary.Item return type. Here is the code:

```
Class SomeClass Implements IComparer(Of C)

Private ReadOnly cache As IDictionary = New Dictionary(Of C, T)

Public Function compare(ByVal chr1 As C, ByVal chr2 As C) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of C).Compare
                Dim fit1 As T = Me.fit(chr1)
                Dim fit2 As T = Me.fit(chr2)
                Dim ret As Integer = fit1.CompareTo(fit2)
                Return ret
            End Function

Public Overridable Function fit(ByVal chr As C) As T
                Dim fits As T = Me.cache.Item(chr)  '<----- Here it fails
                If fits Is Nothing Then    '<------ False, because fits == 0.0
                    fits = fitnessFunc.calculate(chr)  
                    Me.cache.Add(chr, fits)
                End If
                Return fits
            End Function
End Class
```

My `cache` is empty. MSDN says that `IDictionary.Item` returns the element with the specified key, or `Nothing` if the key does not exist. However, my `fits` type is `Double` and it equals `0.0` for unknown reason, though it must be `Nothing`. I am a bit puzzled, how can I do make it work properly? Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You should define your cache as `IDictionary(Of C, T)` otherwise it will be untyped, i.e. it will return Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dictionary contains value types or even reference types that are `Nothing` or nullable types that are `Nothing`, `IDictionary.Item` has no way of telling you whether an item was found in the cache or whether just the type's default value was returned because the key was not found.

Better use the `TryGetValue` method of the dictionary:

```
Dim fits As T
If cache.TryGetValue(chr, fits) Then
    ' We found an item in the cache
Else
    ' We must calculate the missing item and add it to the cache
End If
```

Note: The second parameter of `TryGetValue` is `ByRef` and returns the found item if available.

Answer (score 0):

double is a "value type" (rather then the common "reference type"s). It means that it cannot be Nothing, and when you expect it to be Nothing it will actually be its default value (which is 0.0 in double).

The same is correct also for all the primitive types (int, long, char...) and for Structure types.